# Legends with multiple rows in Matlab

Tags: matlab, legend

How to create a legend with multiple rows or fit a legend within the plotting area. Following is my code and output plot

```
figure;
col = jet(numel(node_id_without_duplicates));
%legend('Node ');

for i=1:numel(node_id_without_duplicates)
    specific_node = node_id_without_duplicates(i);
    legendInfo{i} = ['Node ', num2str(specific_node)];    
    MTBF_Specific_Node; //This is the call of an another tool created by me and not included in this example. 
end    
legend(legendInfo);
```

[image]

Comment: I'm going to be totally honest with you. The problem isn't with the legend. The problem is your plot. It's hideous! You're plotting *waaaaaaay* too many lines. It's a completely useless plot. It conveys no real information that anyone could infer. You need to rethink what information you're trying to show and how best to show it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gridLegend [on FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29248-gridlegend-a-multi-column-format-for-legends). It uses undocumented hidden axes property ScribeLegendListeners, for details please see "[Multi-column (grid) legend](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/multi-column-grid-legend)" on Undocumented MATLAB.

I totally agree with gnovice: the plot is overloaded, rethink it to be more helpful and informative. However, if you want readers to understand nothing and say "Wow, it seems to be a hard task" the plot is just correct.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. However, I asked only for the multi-column legends not for the opinions about my work. It is better not be judgmental before knowing what I wants to achieve.